# Reconstructing Datetime Column from 3 columns (date, time, microseconds) with some Nan

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, finance

I have a high frequency financial database of orders submitted for a particular security (that I unfortunately cannot share here). Each row is an order (new or order update). For each row, there are multiple time information (one "time information" being 3 columns: date, time, microseconds). My goal is to create one column that would combine all three pieces of information. The first and easy to handle case is the order submission.

The column for date (**o_d_be**) is of type **int** (of format yyyymmdd), the column for time (**o_t_be**) is of type **object** (of format hh:mm:ss) and the final column for microseconds (**o_m_be**) is of type **int**. All time information follow this pattern.

I wrote that the order submission is easy to handle because there are no missing values, each order has to have been submitted at some time. For this scenario, i wrote the following code (which can probably be improved):

```
data['o_d_be'] = data['o_d_be'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
    data['o_t_be'] = data['o_t_be'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
    data['o_dtm_be'] = pd.to_datetime(data['o_d_be'] + ' ' + data['o_t_be'], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S') + pd.to_timedelta(data['o_m_be'], unit='us')
```

However when it gets tricky is for order updates. When an order is first submitted, there is no date, time, microseconds for the update in the dedicated columns. These columns are only filled once an already submitted order is updated (in this case, the columns for order submission time do not change). Thus, because of the Nan values, the code above does not work for those columns.

So far, i have tried the following:

```
data['o_d_mo'] = data['o_d_mo'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x==np.nan else str(x))
data['o_t_mo'] = data['o_t_mo'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x==np.nan else str(x))

data['o_dtm_mo'] = np.where(data['o_m_mo']==np.nan, np.nan, pd.to_datetime(data['o_d_mo'] + ' ' + data['o_t_mo'], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S') + pd.to_timedelta(data['o_m_mo'], unit='us'))
```

However, doing so, I get the following error:

```
time data nan nan doesn't match format specified
```

Any idea on how to achieve my objective ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: If you can't share the real data, please create a dummy dataset for use to see its exact structure.

Comment: Here, just did. I basically have some empty cells and struggle to reconstruct the dates in an efficient manner

Comment: Thanks, but please provide this in a reproducible format (**text**, not image) and also provide the matching expected output.

Answer (score 0):

try this, hope it helps, you have to fillna like this:

Option 1: Use pandas mask

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Convert 'o_d_be' and 'o_t_be' to string
data['o_d_be'] = data['o_d_be'].astype(str)
data['o_t_be'] = data['o_t_be'].astype(str)

# Convert 'o_d_be' and 'o_t_be' to datetime
data['o_dtm_be'] = pd.to_datetime(data['o_d_be'] + ' ' + data['o_t_be'], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S') + pd.to_timedelta(data['o_m_be'], unit='us')

# Handle missing values for 'o_d_mo' and 'o_t_mo'
missing_mask = data['o_d_mo'].isnull() | data['o_t_mo'].isnull()
data.loc[missing_mask, 'o_dtm_mo'] = np.nan

# Convert 'o_d_mo' and 'o_t_mo' to string and handle missing values
data['o_d_mo'] = data['o_d_mo'].fillna('').astype(str)
data['o_t_mo'] = data['o_t_mo'].fillna('').astype(str)

# Convert 'o_d_mo' and 'o_t_mo' to datetime
data.loc[~missing_mask, 'o_dtm_mo'] = pd.to_datetime(data['o_d_mo'] + ' ' + data['o_t_mo'], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S') + pd.to_timedelta(data['o_m_mo'], unit='us')
```

Option 2 : Use np.where

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Convert 'o_d_be' and 'o_t_be' to string
data['o_d_be'] = data['o_d_be'].astype(str)
data['o_t_be'] = data['o_t_be'].astype(str)

# Convert 'o_d_be' and 'o_t_be' to datetime
data['o_dtm_be'] = pd.to_datetime(data['o_d_be'] + ' ' + data['o_t_be'], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S') + pd.to_timedelta(data['o_m_be'], unit='us')

# Convert 'o_d_mo' and 'o_t_mo' to string and handle missing values
data['o_d_mo'] = data['o_d_mo'].fillna('').astype(str)
data['o_t_mo'] = data['o_t_mo'].fillna('').astype(str)

# Convert 'o_d_mo' and 'o_t_mo' to datetime and handle missing values
data['o_dtm_mo'] = np.where(
    (data['o_d_mo'] == '') | (data['o_t_mo'] == ''),
    np.nan,
    pd.to_datetime(data['o_d_mo'] + ' ' + data['o_t_mo'], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S') + pd.to_timedelta(data['o_m_mo'], unit='us')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for you insight! However, this does not work because the last line yields the error: "time data nan nan doesn't match format specified".
This is because this part: "data['o_d_mo'] + ' ' + data['o_t_mo']" is equal to " ". Python cannot match " " to the format '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'.
Ideally, i would like the value to be np.nan if there is no time information.

Comment: Thanks again, your second option is basically what I tried above (although I ended up replacing "==np.nan" by ".isnull()":

data['o_dtm_mo'] = np.where(data['o_m_mo'].isnull(), np.nan, pd.to_datetime(data['o_d_mo'] + ' ' + data['o_t_mo'], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S') + pd.to_timedelta(data['o_m_mo'], unit='us'))

However this yields the same error again ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to fix my silly mistake. As I explained before, the date (year, month, day) in the database was initially an int. My previous code (right below) did not work with the columns with empty values because the date, of type int was changed to a float. This was mistake.

```
data['o_d_be'] = data['o_d_be'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
data['o_t_be'] = data['o_t_be'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
data['o_dtm_be'] = pd.to_datetime(data['o_d_be'] + ' ' + data['o_t_be'], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S') + pd.to_timedelta(data['o_m_be'], unit='us')
```

Just converting the float back to an int made your suggested code work.

```
na_mask = data['o_d_mo'].isnull()
data.loc[~na_mask, 'o_d_mo'] = data.loc[~na_mask, 'o_d_mo'].astype(int).astype(str)
data.loc[~na_mask, 'o_d_mo'] = data.loc[~na_mask, 'o_d_mo'].astype(str)
data.loc[~na_mask, 'o_d_mo'] = pd.to_datetime(data['o_d_mo'] + ' ' + data['o_d_mo'], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S') + pd.to_timedelta(data['o_d_mo'], unit='us')
```

Thanks for your help !